# How to write groups of data in CSV file?

Tags: csv, python-3.x

I would like to write clustering results in CSV file. The following code is a small part of k-means clustering, which I used to write the clustering results inCSV file. This example uses excel. I'm first interested in just getting the data in to my program and getting the answer out in CSV file :

```
  with open('some3.csv', 'w') as test_file:
         csv_writer = csv.writer(test_file,dialect='excel',delimiter=',')
         for y,c in enumerate(clusters):
            csv_writer.writerows("cluster %d:" % y +  "\t%s" % cat[i] for i in c)
```

I expect it to be 5 clusters, but instead of getting:

```
cluster 0,value1
cluster 0,value2
cluster 0,value3
cluster 1 value1
cluster 1 value2
.
.
.
```

I have inside my CSV file:

```
c l u s t e r 0 v a l u e 1
c l u s t e r 0 v a l u e 2
.
.
.
```

.
How to join the characters? Any suggestion please?

Answer (score 0):

`csv_writer.writerows` expects a `list` of lists, you gave it a string, which is a list of characters.

Try this:

```
csv_writer.writerow(["cluster %d:" % y] + cat[i] for i in c)
```